# TypeError: How to fix Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, datetimeindex

I want to compute Compound monthly stock returns over 12 months to obtain annual returns.

Here is what I have done, but I am getting an error massage

```
Month_Return = pd.read_csv("Monthly Stock Return.csv") 
Month_Return.set_index('gvkey', inplace=True,drop = False)
Month_Return = Month_Return.rename(columns={"gvkey": "Global_comp_key",
              'iid':"issue identifier","tic":"ticker","conm":"Company name",
              "prccm":"Price_Close_Monthly","exchg":"Stock Exchange 
              ","datadate":"Date})
Month_Return['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(Month_Return['Date'], format='%Y%M%d')
Month_Return = Month_Return.set_index('Date')
###Month_Return['Date'] = Month_Return['Date'].dt.date###

gvkey  issue   datadate    ticker  Company_name  Price_Close_Monthly    Stock Exchange  gsector

1003    1     2003-01-31    ANTQ    A.A             0.0400                  19.0        25.0
1003    1     2004-01-31    ANTQ    A.A.            0.0400                  19.0        25.0
1003    1     2004-01-29    ANTQ    A.A.            0.0400                  19.0        25.0
1003    1     2004-01-31    ANTQ    A.B             0.0400                  19.0        25.0
1003    1     2004-01-30    ANTQ    A.C             0.0001                  19.0        25.0
```

Then I retrieved the colunm I need to calculate the monthly return

```
results_storage['month'] = Month_Return.index.month
results_storage['year'] = Month_Return.index.year

 Date       Price_Close_Monthly     year    month
 2003-01-31     0.0400              2003    1
 2004-01-31     0.0400              2004    1
 2004-01-29     0.0400              2004    1
 2004-01-31     0.0400              2004    1
 2004-01-30     0.0001              2004    1

df_Month_Return_annual =results_storage['Price_Close_Monthly'].
                                     resample('M').ffill().pct_change()
```

I just simplified the script, and am still getting the same error

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but 
got an instance of 'Index'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add convert column to datetimeindex:

```
Month_Return = pd.read_csv("Monthly Stock Return.csv") 
Month_Return.set_index('gvkey', inplace=True,drop = False)
Month_Return['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(Month_Return['Date'], format='%Y%M%d')
Month_Return = Month_Return.set_index('Date')

Month_Return['month'] = Month_Return.index.month
Month_Return['year'] = Month_Return.index.year


df_Month_Return_annual =  (Month_Return['Price_Close_Monthly'].resample('M')
                                .ffill()
                                .pct_change())
```

Comment: I just did that but I am still getting same error response

Comment: This error        `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
`

Comment: @Chukypedro - There is problem use many dataframes, each is necessary datetimeindex, each is necessary convert date column to datetimes and then to datetimeindex

Comment: @Chukypedro - seems a lot of code misisng. How is created `Month_Return_annual` ? How is created `results_storage` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210139/discussion-between-chukypedro-and-jezrael).

Comment: @jazrael I just updated how I got `Month_Return_annual` and `results_storage `  on the post

Comment: I got same error response after simplifying the code as you instructed `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`

Comment: @Chukypedro - do you remove `month_Return['Date'] = Month_Return['Date'].dt.date
` ?

Comment: Yes I removed `month_Return['Date'] = Month_Return['Date'].dt.date`

Comment: I am getting a value error when I update the as you instructed
ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit

Comment: @Chukypedro - I think problem is `ffill` - it is for forward filling, here it seems is necessaty aggregate values per months

Comment: what do think I should use in place of `ffill` ?

Comment: @Chukypedro - I guess `sum` or `mean`, not idea

Comment: both `sum` and `mean` are gives a different output from  `ffill`

Comment: @Chukypedro - Can you add expected output from sample data of `Month_Return['Price_Close_Monthly'].resample('M')
                                .ffill()` ?

Comment: I can't generate an output through the `Month_Return['Price_Close_Monthly'].resample('M') .ffill()' , it give an error response `cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit'

Comment: @Chukypedro - I know, so ask for expected output from sample data manually

Comment: @jezraeI  I don't understand what is mean by generating the sample output manually..

Comment: @Chukypedro - I think I need know, what is output from your data, so ask for output if run `Month_Return['Price_Close_Monthly'].resample('M') .ffill()` (it fail, so need maually add rows to question for verify, how should be changed `Month_Return['Price_Close_Monthly'].resample('M') .ffill()` for expected output with no error)

Comment: I got the same error response as before, I think converting the DataFrame from Index to DatetimeIndex will solve this problem, but I need to know how to acheive that